# Pandas Dataframe Boxplot: Group by one column (without subplots)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I got stuck with a boxplot of a pandas DataFrame and couldn't find any answer to solve my problem.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
subset.head()

   c_el_spot  c_el_tr_neg_cap  c_el_tr_neg_wrk  c_el_tr_pos_cap
1      25.12          20.7075             -0.1                0   
2      25.12          20.7075             -0.1                0   
3      25.12          20.7075              0.0                0   
4      23.64          20.7075              0.0                0   

   c_el_tr_pos_wrk  year  
0                0  2012  
1                0  2012  
2                0  2012  
3                0  2012  
4                0  2012  

subset.tail()
 
        c_el_spot  c_el_tr_neg_cap  c_el_tr_neg_wrk  c_el_tr_pos_cap   
105212      28.02             6.75                0                0   
105213      28.02             6.75                0                0   
105214      28.02             6.75                0                0   
105215      28.02             6.75                0                0   

        c_el_tr_pos_wrk  year  
105211                0  2014  
105212                0  2014  
105213                0  2014  
105214                0  2014  
105215                0  2014
```

And with my plotting code

```
subset.boxplot(column=['c_el_spot', 'c_el_tr_neg_cap', 'c_el_tr_neg_wrk',
                       'c_el_tr_pos_cap', 'c_el_tr_pos_wrk'], by=['year'])
```

delivers a figure with one subplot per column:

[image]

My question is the following: How can I get only one plot with the columns (variables) grouped by the column *year* (5 columns next to each other for 2012, ... )?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `seaborn`, here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=list("ABCD"))
df["Y"] = np.random.randint(0, 4, 1000)
df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars="Y")
df2.sort_values(["Y", "variable"], inplace=True)
seaborn.boxplot(x="Y", y="value", hue="variable", data=df2)
```

the output is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! Having such a feature in pandas would also be cool ;)